# Какое условие поставить на выходе из цикла в методе Рунге Кутта 4 порядка для системы ДУ 1 порядка?

Tags: c++

Пока имеется вот такой код для решения системы ДУ 1 порядка. Если имеется ошибка исправьте пожалуйста.

Вопрос: как мне получить ответ? Мне кажется, надо поставить условие при выходе из цикла, вот только какое?

Условие задачи на фото (4 пункт).

[image: Текст задачи]

Вот что пока у меня имеется:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

double f1(double x1, double x2, double t) // первая функция 
{
    return -52 * x1 - 100 * x2 + exp(-t);               
}

double f2(double x1, double t) // вторая функция
{
    return x1 + sin(t);               
} 

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

    double eps = 0.0001; // погрешность
    double h = 0.1;      // шаг
    //cout << " Введите  h = ";//шаг
    //cin >> h;

    int n = 1000;
    //cout << "Введите n = "; // число точек
    //cin >> n;

    double *x1 = new double[n];
    double *x2 = new double[n];
    double *t1 = new double[n];
    double *t2 = new double[n];
    //cout << "enter x[0] = ";
    //cin >> x[0];
    //cout << "enter y[0] = ";
    //cin >> y[0];
    t1[0] = 0; // начальные значения
    t2[0] = 0; // начальные значения
    x1[0] = 1; // начальные значения
    x2[0] = 0; // начальные значения

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        x1[i] = x1[0] + i * h;
        x2[i] = x2[0] + i * h;
        t1[i] = t1[0] + i * h;
        t2[i] = t2[0] + i * h;

        double k1 =  f1(x1[i - 1], x2[i - 1], t1[i]);
        double k2 =  f1(x1[i - 1] + h / 2., x2[i - 1] + (h * k1) / 2., t1[i]);
        double k3 =  f1(x1[i - 1] + h / 2., x2[i - 1] + (h * k2) / 2., t1[i]);
        double k4 =  f1(x1[i - 1] + h, x2[i - 1] + h * k3, t1[i]);

        double m1 =  f2(x1[i - 1], t2[i]);
        double m2 =  f2(x1[i - 1] + h / 2., t2[i]);
        double m3 =  f2(x1[i - 1] + h / 2., t2[i]);
        double m4 =  f2(x1[i - 1] + h, t2[i]);

        x2[i] = x2[i - 1] + (h / 6.) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2. * k3 + k4);
        x1[i] = x1[i - 1] + (h / 6.) * (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2. * k3 + k4);

        std::cout << t1[i] << ' ' << x1[i] << ' ' << x2[i] << std::endl;
    }

    delete[] x1;
    delete[] x2;
    delete[] t1;
    delete[] t2;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Помнится численные методы считаются до достижения заданной точности (погрешности). Или я не вижу, или действительно нет никакого сравнения чего-либо c eps, который вероятно и задаёт желаемую точность.

Comment: @Sergey, метод Рунге-Кутта считается на фиксированном интервале от *a* до *b* с шагом *h*. Ни о каком *ε* речи идти не может.

Comment: Не может так не может.

Comment: то есть цикл будет как я понял до N=(b-a)/h;

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с того, что непонятно - зачем у вас **две** переменные времени? Они же совпадают. Оставьте одну.

Далее - у вас в условии четко сказано - что `0 <= t <= 2` - вот вам и условие выхода: пока `t <= 2`.

И последнее - зачем вам создавать массивы? Вы же просто выводите результаты расчетов, не храня - можно вполне обойтись без них.

По самим расчетам коэффициентов я пока что не смотрел. Честно говоря, всегда проще написать свое, чем разобраться в объемном чужом :)

Так что [вот мой вариант](http://ideone.com/hrMkKO), писанный для чистого C еще во времена Borland C++ 3.1 :) Это, само собой, далеко не идеал, но, может, на мысли наведет... Там же и ваша функция.

Comment: Что то не то получается

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Ответ не тот, вернее там деление на ноль получается

Comment: @Arhad Может вы что-то посоветуете.

Comment: @SVD102 Там вообще нигде на 0 делить нечего :) Посмотрите тут - http://ideone.com/QsAFTS - только там `h = 0.01`, шаг 0.1 слишком грубый, сходимость вразнос идет...

Comment: @SVD102 Кстати, у вас - я не перепроверял - но уверен в наличии ошибки, хотя бы потому что вы нигде не использовали `m1-m4`...

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста алгоритм. все верно или нет.

Comment: Можете на С++ переписать ваш код, а то я так не разберусь