# Исправить код в методе Рунге-Кутты 4 порядка для системы ДУ 1 порядка

Tags: c++, математика

Вот код для метода Рунге-Кутты 4 порядка для систему ДУ 1 порядка. Вроде все верно, но ответ не правильный. В чем ошибка. Подскажите пожалуйста. Ответ должен быть `x11 = -0,9 x22 = 0,4` (примерно так)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

double f1(double x1, double x2, double t)// первая функция 
{
    return(-52*x1-100*x2+exp(-t));               
}

double f2(double x1, double t)// вторая функция
{
    return(x1+sin(t));               
} 
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

    double h;
    //cout << " Введите  h = ";//шаг
    //cin >> h;
    //int n;
    //n=10000;
    //cout << "Введите n = ";//число точек
    //cin >> n;
    double k1=0;
    double k2=0;
    double k3=0;
    double k4=0;
    double m1=0;
    double m2=0;
    double m3=0;
    double m4=0;
    double x1=0;
    double x2=0;
    double x11=0;
    double x22=0;
    double t=0;
    //cout << "enter x[0] = ";
    //cin >> x[0];
    //cout << "enter y[0] = ";
    //cin >> y[0];
    t = 0; // начальне значения
    x1 = 1; // начальне значения
    x2 = 0; // начальне значения
    h = 0.01;   // шаг

    int i = 0;

    while(t<2.0)
    {

        k1 =  h*f1(x1, x2, t);
        m1 =  h*f2(x1, t);

        k2 =  h*f1(x1 + k1/2., x2 + m1/2., t+h/2.);
        m2 =  h*f2(x1 + k1/2., t+h/2.);

        k3 =  h*f1(x1 + k2/2., x2 + m2/2., t+h/2.);
        m3 =  h*f2(x1 + k2/2., t+h/2.);

        k4 =  h*f1(x1 + k3, x2 + m3, t+h);
        m4 =  h*f2(x1 + k3, t+h);

        x11 = x1 + (1. / 6.)*(k1 + 2. * k2 + 2. * k3 + k4);
        x22 = x2 + (1. / 6.)*(m1 + 2. * m2 + 2. * m3 + m4);

        i++;
        x1 = x1 + h;
        x2 = x2 + h;
        t = t + h;

        cout<<"t = "<< t << " x11 = "<< x11 << " x22 = " << x22 << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какое условие поставить на выходе из цикла в методе Рунге Кутта 4 порядка для системы ДУ 1 порядка?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/514061/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%83%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%a0%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%b5-%d0%9a%d1%83%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b0-4-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b8)

Comment: @pavel Я думаю что нет

Answer (score 1):

Ну смотрите сами, что вы делаете -

```
    x1 = x1 + h;
    x2 = x2 + h;
```

Т.е. все посчитанное теряем, коту под хвост, и заменяем значение простой линейной функцией?...

Вот решение "по-вашему":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double f1(double x1, double x2, double t) // первая функция 
{
    return -52 * x1 - 100 * x2 + exp(-t);               
}

double f2(double x1, double t) // вторая функция
{
    return x1 + sin(t);               
} 

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL,"rus");

    double h = 0.01;      // шаг

    double x1 = 1.0;
    double x2 = 0.0;
    double t  = 0.0;
    cout << setw(10) << t << setw(12) << x1 << setw(12) << x2 << endl;

    while (t <= 2.0)
    {

        double k1 =  h*f1(x1,x2,t);
        double m1 =  h*f2(x1,t);

        double k2 =  h*f1(x1+k1/2,x2+m1/2,t+h/2);
        double m2 =  h*f2(x1+k1/2,t+h/2);

        double k3 =  h*f1(x1+k2/2,x2+m2/2,t+h/2);
        double m3 =  h*f2(x1+k2/2,t+h/2);

        double k4 =  h*f1(x1+k3,x2+m3,t+h);
        double m4 =  h*f2(x1+k2,t+h);

        x1 += (k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4)/6;
        x2 += (m1+2*m2+2*m3+m4)/6;
        t += h;

        cout << setw(10) << t << setw(12) << x1 << setw(12) << x2 << endl;

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/2cerCs